# Validating List nested in a Map with Hibernate Validator 5.2+

Tags: java, java-8, hibernate-validator

I'm using the Hibernate Validator 5.2, which features support for Java 8 type_use annotations.  I'd like to be able to validate the content of a List inside a Map -- in other words, I just want it to cascade down and validate the contents of Maps and Lists, no matter how they are nested.

A simple Map example:

```
Map<String, List<Promotion>> promotionsByGroupName = ...;
```

What I'd like is to be able to do:

```
@Valid
Map<String, List<@Valid Promotion>> promotionsByGroupName = ...;
```

However that doesn't work as the standard @Valid annotation cannot be put on that element.  So I created a custom annotation that I'm allowed to place there:

```
@Valid
Map<String, List<@ValidPart Promotion>> promotionsByGroupName = ...;
```

However, the validator associated with @ValidPart never gets triggered.

The closest I managed to get was to put the @ValidPart annotation on the List like this:

```
@Valid
Map<String, @ValidPart List<Promotion>> promotionsByGroupName = ...;
```

...and then unwrap the List in the associated validator to get validate the elements (which unfortunately involves calling a Validator inside the ConstraintValidator and "rewriting" the resulting ConstraintViolations).

My question is therefore, is there a way to do these kinds of nested validations without traversing the List myself?  The constraint violation paths this generates are not quite what I'm looking for, as they look like:

```
promotionsByGroupName[GroupName].[0].name cannot be null
```

Instead of (no dot between Map key name and Index):

```
promotionsByGroupName[GroupName][0].name cannot be null
```

The [0] part is the index of the List which I added myself using addPropertyName in this code:

```
for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : validator.validate(value)) {
    NodeBuilderCustomizableContext builder = context
        .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(violation.getMessage())
        .addPropertyNode("[" + i + "]");

    for (String nodeName : violation.getPropertyPath().toString().split("\\.")) {
        builder = builder.addPropertyNode(nodeName);
    }

    builder.addConstraintViolation();
}
```

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that calling a Validator inside a ConstraintValidator is a useless exercise, as the original ConstraintDescriptor that failed cannot be retained in the new constraint violations.  It looks like the JSR-303 spec is good for simple person/address violations, but is severely lacking when used on complex real world data structures.  Rolling my own.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. This type of nested unwrapping is currently not supported with Hibernate Validator.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, you might create a specific collection type `Promotions` which you use as map values instead of `List<Promotion>`.